# Magento categories issue & site timeout

Tags: category

I'm helping a friend w/ a Magento installation and have hit a couple of weird things happening.

First, the original issue was that when clicking on the category names for existing categories, no edit screen appears, instead it just shows the 'new root category' panel.

Then this. In clicking through a couple of categories in the admin panel, after about 5 clicks of this working, it got stuck on the loading screen. Now suddenly I can't load the admin panel or the front end website. I even tried a ping test and had 100% packet loss.

I rebooted, rebooted the router, tried different computers and nothing works - the site is still timing out.

I went to a different wifi network and now I could get in - for about the first 5 clicks looking at the original problem before it shut me out again.

I'm not familiar with Magento; I have no access to the actual server either in this case. Does Magento have some kind of feature that would block an IP? This whole thing seems fishy and I don't even know what to try next.

Comment: Regarding the blocking: Magento does not. The server or host might. See if there are any server error logs you can check. Probably tripping some kind of firewall rule.

Comment: found the issue and it seems related to the original question. I was blocked by the firewall for invalid login attempts. The login attempts appear to be coming from the ajax calls on edit category requests.